# Selecting XML when there are multiple nodes with different attributes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have XML that looks like this:

```xml
<config>
    <backup>
        <environment>
            <server name="exampleserver2" type="FM">
                <utility hfmcopyapp="C:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\products\FinancialManagement\Utilities\HfmCopyAppCmd_x64.exe"/>
                <utility lcm="C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\FM1\bin\Utility.bat"/>
            </server>
        </environment>
    </backup>
</config>
```

The PowerShell code I am using is (*updated, reflects working code*):

```
function Get-ServerAttrByXmlTag
{
    [OutputType([string])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$server,
        [string]$type,
        [string]$feature,
        [string]$xmltag,
        [string]$attribute

    )

    if ($type)
    {
        $Value = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//server[@name='$server' and @type='$type']/$xmltag/@$attribute").'#text'
    }
    else
    {
        $Value = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//server[@name='$server']/$xmltag/@$attribute").'#text'
    }
    $Value
}
```

The error I get is non-terminating and the function is able to find the attribute. It's just that the first iteration of element `<utility>` doesn't contain the attribute `lcm`, so it throws this error:

```
ERROR: Select-Object : Property "lcm" cannot be found. Common.ps1 (114, 5):
ERROR: At Line: 114 char: 5
ERROR: +              Select-Object -ExpandProperty $attribute
ERROR: +              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (utility:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
ERROR:
```

Whenever there are multiple `<utility>` nodes if the first one doesn't contain the `$atttribute` I am looking for an error record is throw. It will eventually find the `utility.lcm` path but not without an error being throw.

For example if I am looking for `utility.lcm` The first utility node isn't `lcm`, it's `hfmcopyapp`. So an error is thrown because `lcm` wasn't found.

How can I select the correct node/attribute without throwing an error?

There's no rearranging the XML either. It has to work with the nodes attributes given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would practically always recommend using `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` with an [XPath expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) over dot-access, with very few exceptions.

For selecting a node with a particular attribute use a predicate that checks for the presence of that attribute:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//utility[@lcm]')
```

For selecting just the attribute select the attribute element instead of its node:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//utility/@lcm')
```

If you need further filter criteria applied to ancestor nodes you can do that as well:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//server[@name='$server' and @type='$type']/utility/@lcm")
```

Comment: Can i do something like $Value = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//config.$feature.environment.server[@name='$server' and @type='$type']/$xmltag/@$attribute")

Comment: That should probably be `$Value = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//config/$feature/environment/server[@name='$server' and @type='$type']/$xmltag/@$attribute").'#text'`, but yes, that should work. However, if you actually need to do something like that I would very much suspect you're facing an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: yes I probably do suffer from the X-Y problem, and I spoke too soon. I am still facing the same error message being put in the error record. I will sort it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I updated the powershell code to reflect the current state of the function

Comment: @todd1215 You cannot use dot-notation in an XPath expression. `//config.$feature.environment.server[...]` will look for a node `<config.backup.environment.server>`, which doesn't exist. Please take another look at my first comment. The node names in the expression MUST be separated with slashes.

Comment: Yes I realized that my function had a bad implementation of the XPath I fixed it and rerunning.

Comment: @todd1215 So, are you still seeing errors? I'm pretty certain that the updated code in your question does not throw that error anymore.

Comment: Nope...after some code review I found a duplicate function in another file defined the same way I had originally done. Removing the duplicate and updating the original function has resolved the issue. I've updated the initial post to reflect the fixed code.